# The Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

is there a way to extend the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation 
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}Ks^2}=\left(\frac{K}{2\pi}\right)^{1/2}\int_{–\infty}^\infty e^{–Kx^2+Ksx}dx$$
to the case $e^{\frac{1}{2}Ks^p}$ for $p \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: To the downvoters: This is an excellent and deep question. +1

Answer (score 6):

@HyyFly: It would be nice to elaborate a bit on your question and in particular give some motivation. What applications do you have in mind for possible generalizations of the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation? The latter is just the physics parlance for the formula for the Fourier transform of a Gaussian, *used in reverse*. In any case, if you want to entice people to write useful and thoughtful answers, how you write your question must show some effort.

As to the question itself:

The problem of figuring out when "simple functions" like the exponential of a quadratic has a simple Fourier transform was addressed in the article ["When is the Fourier transform of an elementary function elementary?"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00029-002-8101-7) by Etingof, Kazhdan and Polishchuk in Selecta Math. 2002.

If all you want is a way of breaking quantum field theory vertices with $p$ legs into trivalent vertices, then one can do that by iterating the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation (aka intermediate field representation). See, for instance, the article ["Loop vertex expansion for $\Phi^{2k}$ theory in zero dimension"](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3460320) by Rivasseau and Wang in J. Math. Phys. 2010 and the follow up ["Note on the intermediate field representation of $\phi^{2k}$ theory in zero dimension"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11040-018-9281-5) by Lionni and Rivasseau.

Comment: For a QFT where you want to split fermion multilinears into a bilinear and auxiliary field there is also https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06494

Answer (score 2):

As Abdelmalek Abdesselam mentions you need to iterate such transformations. Let me sketch one way this can work, (in a formal perturbative sense):

Starting from $\exp(s^p)$, you can consider the integral over two new variables $x,y$
$$
\int dx \int dy \exp(s^{p-2} y + x(y-s^2))
$$
Clearly doing the $x,y$ integrations together will set $y=s^2$ (and there will also be some numerical prefactor you can adjust) so you obtain the original term $\exp(s^p)$.

However the log of the integrand here is now of order $p-1$ rather than $p$, so you can do another such transformation involving $s,x,y$ and more new variables to further reduce the total order until you hit $p=3$, where the procedure terminates.

There is a mathematical physics interpretation here, if you are interested: if we view $\exp(s^p)$ as the (exponential of an) action of some physical system, and canonically associate to that an L-infinity algebra, what this procedure is doing is producing a *strictification* of said algebra: namely an L-infinity algebra quasi-isomorphic (read: physically equivalent) to the original one, but all of whose higher (than bilinear) brackets vanish. The end result looks like a Chern-Simons type theory.